# Grpc - Passing different objects into grpc service method

Tags: grpc, grpc-java

In Chat Service, we get the request from client and send a response based on it.
But My scenario is, Server has to send some different objects from a outside method of the class.

For example,

```java
public StreamObserver<SalaryDetails> message(StreamObserver<Employee> responseObserver) {
    observers.add(responseObserver);

    return new StreamObserver<SalaryDetails>() {

        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            observers.remove(responseObserver); 
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable arg0) {
            observers.remove(responseObserver); 
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(SalaryDetails details) {
            for(StreamObserver<MetricsToVE> observer : observers) {
                **observer.onNext(Employee.newBuilder()
                    .setName("AA")
                    .setCity("B")
                    .build());**
            }
        }
    };
}
```

In below statement I have hardcoded the fields, how should I pass an object from a different method into the grpc service class.

Comment: If the server is sending different objects to the client, it sounds like those should be different rpc methods. Otherwise, the client wouldn't know what kind of object was being returned.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on why the response values vary:

1. If the client can predict what the response type is based on the request, then you should probably have the client call different methods based on the type
2. If the possible options are well-known to the API, then you can use [protobuf's `oneof`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#oneof).
3. If the data is arbitrary, then you can use [protobuf's `Any`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#any)

It seems like #2 is likely your case.